# Cairo introspection errors in Eclipse with PyDev `TypeError: Couldn't find conversion for foreign struct 'cairo.Context'`

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse-plugin, gtk, pydev, cairo

I am working on adding a printer interface to some home-brewed Python3 code with a Gtk3 UI, using (mostly) Eclipse Indigo with the PyDev plugin.

While developing the PrintOperation callbacks I found a problem where apparently the gi-introspection fails to find the right underlying library struct for the Cairo Context. The error reported in the console is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bob/Projects/MovieList/src/MovieList/MovieListIO.py", line 203, in on_printDialog_draw_page
    cr = context.get_cairo_context()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: Couldn't find conversion for foreign struct 'cairo.Context'
```

At first I thought this was something to do with Eclipse and/or PyDev, because I could run the program within Idle without any error messages. But then I found that when the program was packaged for deployment with the built-in command-line Python tools, the installed version also gave the error. So, I wrote a couple of test scripts abstracting the printer functionality to try to isolate what was going on. In both cases, the key line is in the `on_printOperation_draw_page()` callback (marked with comments).

Here is the first test script (Script 1, printTestPdf.py), which loads a pdf file using Poppler, and prints it using the system print dialog:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
import os
from gi.repository import Gtk, Poppler

testFile = 'file://' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'printTestPdf.pdf')
pdfDocument = Poppler.Document.new_from_file(testFile, None)

class Example(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()                
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):    
        self.set_title("Print Pdf Test")
        self.resize(230, 150)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)                
        printButton = Gtk.Button('Press Me')
        self.add(printButton)
        printButton.connect('clicked', self.on_printButton_clicked)
        self.show_all()

    def on_printButton_clicked(self, widget):
        """
        Handler for the button click.
        """                
        printOperation = Gtk.PrintOperation()
        printOperation.connect('draw-page', self.on_printOperation_draw_page)
        printOperation.set_job_name('Print Pdf Test')
        printOperation.set_n_pages(pdfDocument.get_n_pages())
        printOperation.run(Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT_DIALOG,
                           parent=self)

    def on_printOperation_draw_page(self, printOperation, context, pageNo):
        """
        Handler for the draw-page signal from the printOperation.
        """
        cr = context.get_cairo_context() # <-- THIS IS THE LINE
        page = pdfDocument.get_page(pageNo)
        page.render_for_printing(cr)

def main():            
    app = Example()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
```

This is the second script (Script 2, printTestHtml.py), which is almost identical, except it loads an HTML file for printing using weasyprint:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

import os
from gi.repository import Gtk
from weasyprint import HTML

testFile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'printTestHtml.html')
pdfDocument = HTML(filename=testFile).render()

class Example(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()           
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):    
        self.set_title("Print Html Test")
        self.resize(230, 150)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)           
        printButton = Gtk.Button('Press Me')
        self.add(printButton)
        printButton.connect('clicked', self.on_printButton_clicked)
        self.show_all()

    def on_printButton_clicked(self, widget):
        """
        Handler for the button click.
        """            
        printOperation = Gtk.PrintOperation()
        printOperation.connect('begin-print', self.on_printOperation_begin_print)
        printOperation.connect('draw-page', self.on_printOperation_draw_page)
        printOperation.set_job_name('Print HTML Test')
        printOperation.set_n_pages(len(pdfDocument.pages))
        printOperation.run(Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT_DIALOG,
                           parent=self)

    def on_printOperation_draw_page(self, printOperation, context, pageNo):
        """
        Handler for the draw-page signal from the printOperation.
        """
        cr = context.get_cairo_context() # <-- THIS IS THE LINE
        page = pdfDocument.pages[pageNo]
        page.paint(cr) # <-- there is a separate issue here

def main():        
    app = Example()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
```

Both scripts generate an internal pdf document, which is used to render each page on request via the `PrintOperation` `draw_page` callback.

Now, whether and how the scripts succeed or fail depends on the context in which they are run. Script 1 always works, except if it is run after a failure of Script 2 in Idle. Script 2 always generates the error message as reported above when run in Eclipse. In Idle, Script 2's behaviour is complex. Sometimes it fails due to a second problem (marked), and does not exhibit the first failure. However, for reasons I have yet to establish, every so often it generates the original error, and when it does, it keeps doing it and Script 1 show the error too, until Idle is re-booted. Running directly from the command line matches the behaviour in Eclipse. I have tried to summarise this behaviour below:

```
*   Eclipse
    -   Script 1: Always OK
    -   Script 2: Always Fails
*   Command line
    -   Script 1: Always OK
    -   Script 2: Always Fails
*   Idle
    -   Script 1: OK, except after failure of Script 2
    -   Script 2: Intermittent Fail. Knock-on to future runs (up to next error)
```

This pattern of failure may help determine what the root problem is, but it is beyond me to understand it.

Ignoring the bizarre behaviour in Idle, it is possible the difference between Script 1 and Script 2 holds a clue to my original problem. Why does Script 1 run successfully, while Script 2 generates the introspection error?

If you can offer any suggestions as to what is going wrong I would be most grateful. If you can come up with a solution I will be delighted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view of the lack of response I have come up with the following workaround, which uses `WebKit` instead of `weasyprint` to do the parsing, rendering and administration of the printing from html:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

import os
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit

testFile = 'file://' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'printTestHtml.html')

class Example(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()        
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):    
        self.set_title("Print Html WebKit Test")
        self.resize(230, 150)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        printButton = Gtk.Button('Press Me')
        self.add(printButton)
        printButton.connect('clicked', self.on_printButton_clicked)

        self.show_all()

    def on_printButton_clicked(self, widget):
        webView = WebKit.WebView()
        webView.load_uri(testFile)
        webFrame = webView.get_main_frame()
        webFrame.print_full(Gtk.PrintOperation(),
                            Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT_DIALOG)

def main():    
    app = Example()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
```

What I *think* is going on is that somehow weasyprint interferes with the introspection process. I have raised this as a bug on the weasyprint home page on [github](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/119?source=cc).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps I was looking for a solution to the cairo error.

Had this cairo error happen on my RPi3 with Pandas and Matplotlib. The plot window was showing up blank.
I had to run `sudo apt-get install python-gobject-cairo`
Based on this: https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/issues/221